# Concatenate strings in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I need to concatenate path string as follows, so I added the following lines to my `.emacs` file:

```
(setq org_base_path "~/smcho/time/")
(setq org-default-notes-file-path (concatenate 'string org_base_path "notes.org"))
(setq todo-file-path (concatenate 'string org_base_path "gtd.org"))
(setq journal-file-path (concatenate 'string org_base_path "journal.org"))
(setq today-file-path (concatenate 'string org_base_path "2010.org"))
```

When I do <kbd>C-h v</kbd> `today-file-path` <kbd>RET</kbd> to check, it has no variable assigned.

What's wrong with my code? Is there any other way to concatenate the path string?

### EDIT

I found that the problem was caused by the wrong setup, the code actually works. Thanks for the answers which are better than my code.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use `(concat "foo" "bar")` rather than `(concatenate 'string "foo" "bar")`.  Both work, but of course the former is shorter.

Comment: concatenate isn't even bound in my version of emacs. Was concatenate removed or something?

Comment: @Cameron Looks like `concatenate` is an obsolete alias for `cl-concatenate` that is only available if you load the obsolete library `cl`.

Answer (score 30):

Use *expand-file-name* to build filenames relative to a directory:

```
(let ((default-directory "~/smcho/time/"))
  (setq org-default-notes-file-path (expand-file-name "notes.org"))
  (setq todo-file-path (expand-file-name "gtd.org"))
  (setq journal-file-path (expand-file-name "journal.org"))
  (setq today-file-path (expand-file-name "2010.org")))
```

Answer (score 28):

First of all, don't use "_"; use '-' instead.
Insert this into your .emacs and restart emacs (or evaluate the S-exp in a buffer) to see the effects:

```
(setq org-base-path (expand-file-name "~/smcho/time"))

(setq org-default-notes-file-path (format "%s/%s" org-base-path "notes.org")
      todo-file-path              (format "%s/%s" org-base-path "gtd.org")
      journal-file-path           (format "%s/%s" org-base-path "journal.org")
      today-file-path             (format "%s/%s" org-base-path "2010.org"))
```

Comment: See @Jürgen's answer for a better way to construct a path from multiple elements.